# Are POST requests with only path variables and no body a bad practice?

Tags: http, spring-boot, post

I'm in a situation where I need to execute a `POST` request only with path parameters and no content.

Since I'm using Spring Boot, I have a `@PostMapping` annotated method with something like this:

```
@PostMapping("/firstEntity/{firstEntityId}/secondEntity/{secondEntityId}")
```

I've read some topics and questions about sending a `POST` request without body, and found that **sending a POST request without body, but with *headers*** isn't a bad practice. It's just uncommon.

But, in that situation where I'm not sending anything nor at the content nor at the headers, is this a bad practice?

For those who are wondering why am I doing this, the fact is that I need to execute a method in my service layer that relates a record from one table with a record from another table.

Comment: What is the purpose of the POST, in this example? POST is for creating a resource; is that actually what the intention of your POST is?

Comment: @ChrisCousins I need to execute a method in my service layer that relates a record from one table with a record from another table. Basically, yes, it's creating a resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET requests can be bookmarked and hit from going to the url in the browser.

POST requests can't be bookmarked and can't be hit from going to the url in the browser.

You're correct in doing this through a POST because you don't want it to be bookmarked or accidentally hit

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly valid to have a POST with no body and in many circumstances it makes a lot of sense. An alternative would be:

```
POST /firstEntity/{firstEntityId}/secondEntity
```

and then supply secondEntityId as the body of that POST.